# Using Pickle to serialise large objects - what causes 'Memory error'

Tags: json, python-3.x, pickle

I'm pickling a very large (both in terms of properties and in terms raw size) class. I've been picking it no problem with pickle using pickle.dump, until I hit just under 4GB and now I consistently get 'Memory Error'. I've also tried using json.dump (and I get 'is not JSON serializable' error). I've also tried Hickle but I get the same error with Hickle as I do with Pickle.

I can't post all the code here (it's very long) but in essence It's a class that holds a dictionary of values from another class - something like this:

```
class one:
  def __init__(self):
    self.somedict = {}

  def addItem(self,name,item)
    self.somedict[name] = item

class two:
  def __init__(self):
   self.values = [0]*100
```

Where name is a string and item is an instance of the class two object.

There's a lot more code to it, but this is where the vast majority of things are held. Is there a reliable and ideally *fast* solution to saving this object to file and then being able to reload it at a later time. I save it every few thousand iterations (as a backup incase something goes wrong, so I need it to be reasonably quick).

Thanks!

Edit #1:

I've just thought that it might be useful to include some details on my system. I have 64Gb of ram - so I don't *think* pickling a 3-4GB file should cause this type of issue (although I could be wrong on this!).

Answer (score 0):

You probably checked this one first but just in case: Did you make sure your Python installation 64 bit? The 3-4GB immediately reminded me of the memory limit of 32bit applications.

I found [this resource](https://www.pythonpool.com/python-memory-error/) quite useful for analyzing and resolving some of the more common memory related issues with Python.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hadn't checked this recently (and this *is* a new environment) but unfortunately I'm using 64 bit already. I've noticed the while pickling the memory usage skyrockets, but I'm not sure why?

Comment: Pickling is indeed quite memory intensive, mainly due to the fact that in order to serialize the data it has to create an in memory copy of the object resulting in a memory spike that might cause the error.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't be of much help though. You might try using protocol version 5 if you're not doing so already (available since Python 3.8 I think and handling large objects a lot better than version 4) `pickle.dump(obj, fp, protocol=5)`. You might also take a look at [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as an alternative. Good luck! ;)